# How can I run a script on my server using gcloud compute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, google-compute-engine

I'm deploying my Rails apps on Compute Engine, and my code is hosted at Github.  I want to push changes to my master branch, and then execute a gcloud compute command to tell my instances to pull the master repository and restart nginx.

If I can't execute a script from SSH, what's the best way to tell my instances to update to the latest git commit and restart, so my apps are running on the latest codebase?

I've tried using the Release Pipeline, but it doesn't seem to work for Rails.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a 'Startup Script'[1] along with a scheduled reboot of the machine? Every time your machine reboots, the script will get the new code. Or is that causing issues for you?

[1] https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript

Comment: You are correct, I built a simple startup script that runs the git pull and restart nginx, so now if I reboot, it does what I need. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a server automation system for something like this.  For example:

- [Salt Stack](http://www.saltstack.com/) allows [remote command invocation](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/walkthrough.html#helpful-functions-to-know) as well as a thousand other useful server management features.
- [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/), which is built on top of SSH, is great for [running commands remotely](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html#your-first-commands).

Most other server automation systems (chef, puppet) also provide some way to run a command remotely.